# Polynomial regression with Apache Maths (Java)

Tags: java, apache, regression

Could anybody help me make a polynomial regression (order 2) with the Apache Math library.

The following data should give this equation: 39.79 x^2 - 497.66 x + 997.45
(computed by Excel with r2 = 0.9998)

```
// coding style from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fitting.html    

double[] y = { 540.0, 160.0, -140.0, -360.0, -480.0, -560.0, -540.0, -440.0, -260.0, 0.0, 340.0};              
        final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
        for (double figure:y){
            obs.add(1.0, figure);
        }
        final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(2);
        final double[] coeff = fitter.fit(obs.toList());
        System.out.println("coef="+Arrays.toString(coeff));
```

Here are the regression coefficients provided by the previous code:

```
coef=[-53.73522460839947, -52.22329678670934, -52.22329678670934]
```

Obviously, there's something I'm missing...

Thanks for your kind help

Dom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All your data points are at x = 1.

```
obs.add(1.0, figure);!!!!
```

instead of 1.0 there should be x value, if they are evenly spaced from zero than use for loop and ix instead of 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. But according to the doc, the first item is the weight (" ...If no such information exist and all points should be treated the same, it is safe to put 1.0 as the weight for all points"). In addition, what do you call ix ? So I don't see your point.

Comment: acording to the doc add(x,y) == add(1.0, x,y) if you provide only two arguments the first is x value not the weight. Secondly, you should be worried yourself that you do regression without x values at all. As for ix, I mean it fyou have evenly spread points, the code would look like: for(int ix=0;ix<y.length;ix++) obs.add(ix,y[ix])

Comment: OK. Got it. You're absolutely right. That gives: coef=[997.45, -497.66, 39.79]. The last one for x^2, the middle one for x and the first one for the constant. Thanks a lot Zielu for your patience. I appreciate.