# Polynomial Regression with Apache Maths 3.6.1

Tags: java, apache, regression, non-linear-regression

Can someone let me know how I can do Polynomial Regression with [Apache Maths](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3) 3.6.1

Below are the data points I used for my testing

```
60735214881.391304  1520254800000.000000
60697824142.469570  1520258400000.000000
60651182200.208694  1520262000000.000000
60684367132.939130  1520265600000.000000
60676588613.008700  1520269200000.000000
60641816564.869570  1520272800000.000000
60604714824.233510  1520276400000.000000
60580042814.330440  1520280000000.000000
60536134542.469570  1520283600000.000000
60566323732.034780  1520287200000.000000
60578775249.252174  1520290800000.000000
60547382844.104350  1520294400000.000000
60536776546.802160  1520298000000.000000
60474342718.330440  1520301600000.000000
60452725477.286960  1520305200000.000000
60486821569.669560  1520308800000.000000
60247997139.995674  1520312400000.000000
60248432181.426090  1520316000000.000000
60217476247.373920  1520319600000.000000
60170744493.634780  1520323200000.000000
```

My code looks like below

```
private void polynomialFitter(List<List<Double>> pointlist) {
        final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(2);
        final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
        for (List<Double> point : pointlist) {
            obs.add(point.get(1), point.get(0));
        }
        double[] fit = fitter.fit(obs.toList());
        System.out.printf("\nCoefficient %f, %f, %f", fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]);
    }
```

The coefficients are reported as

```
Coefficient 12.910025, 0.000000, 0.000000
```

But these does not seem to be quite correct. If I use the same dataset in
[Online Polynimal Regression](http://polynomialregression.drque.net/online.php) and in [archanoid online regression](https://arachnoid.com/polysolve/) - both reports same value as `654623237474.68250993904929103762, 28.75921919628759991574, -0.00000000023885199278`

Can someone let me know what is going wrong? I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563361/polynomial-regression-with-apache-maths-java) but that is not helping me.

Comment: Note that both X and Y data has very large offsets and small variation, so for numerical precision when squaring or cubing the values in a polynomial I personally would first subtract either the average value or minimum value for each column. In the final result you can add those values back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered in [apache-commons](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201803.mbox/%3CCAF6DVKPZ4MxinJuHMZeRuYyvc6aYY%3Dn1DP7p0yxyAKWKWDuSCA%40mail.gmail.com%3E) mailing list

> Polynomial regression is not the same as curve fitting.  To do
>   polynomial regression in Commons Math, use the
>   OLSMultipleLinearRegression class, using, X, X^2 etc as the
>   independent variables (as your second reference above shows).

A sample code is like below

```
private OLSMultipleLinearRegression getMultipleLinearRegression(List<List<Double>> pointlist) {
    OLSMultipleLinearRegression regression = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();
    double y[] = new double[pointlist.size()];
    double x[][] = new double[pointlist.size()][2];
    int c = 0;
    for (List<Double> point : pointlist) {
        y[c] = point.get(0);
        x[c][0] = point.get(1);
        x[c][1] = Math.pow(point.get(1), 2);
        regression.newSampleData(y, x);
        c++;
    }
    System.out.printf("\tR2 = %f", regression.calculateRSquared());
    return regression;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Commons Math 3.6.1, I get almost identical parameters when fitting a cubic to data using `PolynomialCurveFitter` and tuk's `OLSMultipleLinearRegression` suggestion.

The curve gives correct interpolations in the range of the data, but you've got to be careful about extrapolations.

The `PolynomialCurveFitter` code was half the number of lines of the `OLSMultipleLinearRegression` code.